# My iAd doesn't change orientation as my layout does

Tags: iphone, ipad, user-interface, iad

On adding iAd with the help of creating shared instance. On running app `UI` alignment changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Comment: return Orientation in this